# rails 3.0.3 check if boolean value is true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to check if a value is true or false.

```
<% if item.active? %>
    <%= image_tag('on.png', :alt => "Active", :border => 0) %>
<% else %> 
    <%= image_tag('off.png', :alt => "Inactive", :border => 0) %>
<% end %>
```

That doesn't work, but this works?

```
<% if item.active == true %>
    <%= image_tag('on.png', :alt => "Active", :border => 0) %>
<% else %> 
    <%= image_tag('off.png', :alt => "Inactive", :border => 0) %>
<% end %>
```

Shouldn't the first method work or am I missing something?

Comment: I know you already have accepted an answer, but I wonder, what do you mean by "does not work"? Also, remember that 'true' in ruby means "everything (!) except false and nil". For example 0, "0", empty array and so on, all represent truth. Maybe that was the problem?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

if this line works:

```
if item.active == true
```

then

```
if item.active
```

will also work.  `if item.active?` works only if there is a method whose name is actually `active?`, which is usually the convention for naming a method that returns true or false.

Comment: Just as an aside, rails adds in the <attribute>? method for boolean fields.  This will return false if the value is set to false (ie 0/f/whatever) or nil.  So, if you have an active attribute that is based on a boolean database field, then .active? *should* work.  Generally though, it's better to just say "if item.active" as 動靜能量 suggests.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you assuming `item.active` is truly a boolean value. Unless there is a method defined for `item.active?` your example will only return a no-method error.

```
<% if item.active %>
    <%= image_tag('on.png', :alt => "Active", :border => 0) %>
<% else %> 
    <%= image_tag('off.png', :alt => "Inactive", :border => 0) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other way is using single line if else

```
<%= active ? here is your statement for true : here is your statement for false %>
```

For `active?` to work there should be an `def active?` method in your item object.